# How to fix a simple Dlookup - not working

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get username data from one table [tbl_ComputerNames] into a displayed form control:  `Me.UN`

Either of these should work as far as I know...

```
 Me.UN = DLookup("[UN]", "tbl_ComputerNames", "[PCName] = '" & Forms![frm_CurrentConnections]!PCName & "'")
```

or

```
 Me.UN = DLookup("[UN]", "tbl_ComputerNames","[PCName] = '" & Me.PCName & "'")
```

I get the same error from both formats

> Runtime 3075 - Syntax error in string in query expression
>   '[PCNAME]='HD0HD8F2'

The PCName data is a string of text and numerals I am treating as text, I thought correctly.

I have tried replacing the criteria with known data and it works fine, which leads me to believe the error is in how I'm referencing the criteria...

I even had the PCName go to a msgbox instead of to the form criteria and it seemed to work fine, even displaying the correct PCName. But as soon as I put in the criteria again it goes back to the same issue.

I feel that I'm overlooking or forgetting some simple step or action. I have checked a bunch of pages about similar problems and I just can't seem to find anything obvious I'm doing wrong.

EDIT- exact error string below pasted from debug window as requested (including the full-stop at the end)
Syntax error in string in query expression '[PCName] = 'H5CG7385KF7'.

EDIT:
I used a function to remove any Nulls from the input string - as below - this did not appear to fix the problem and the error is still the same if I use the concatenated code. - at this point i will run with the unconcatenated code unless anyone can think of anything else to try?

```
Public Function StripNull(ByVal InString As String) As String

'Input: String containing null terminator (Chr(0))'Returns: all character before the null terminator

Dim iNull As Integer

If Len(InString) > 0 Then
iNull = InStr(InString, vbNullChar)

Select Case iNull
Case 0
    StripNull = InString

Case 1
    StripNull = ""

Case Else
   StripNull = Left$(InString, iNull - 1)

End Select

End If
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the syntax. Instead of DLookup, can include the lookup table in the form's RecordSource. Just don't allow edits to the fields from lookup table. Or is there a combobox on form for selecting computer using tblComputerNames as its RowSource? Include UN field in the combo RowSource then reference that column to display value in a textbox.

Comment: Is the error text exact?  I ask because the error text has the where expression wrapped in single quotes, so that one would expect `'[PCNAME]='HD0HD8F2''`, but notice that the ending single-quote is missing.  Typo?  Or does this indicate that DLookup is not receiving the closing quote correctly?  Are there stray characters inside the [PCNAME] field?  (Also, please format code as code and use code or quote formatting for error text also.  You can click the help (?) buttons and links to get help on formatting code properly.)

Comment: Try this to get exact error text.  Add `On Error Resume Next` before the line, then add `Debug.Print Err.Description`, then copy and paste err text from immediate window into your question.

Comment: I suspect that your PCNames(s) in your table are null terminated. Null termination will end the string, hence the single quote at the end will be ignored and you'll get the exact error you're getting right now.

Comment: Since I'm the one causing the fuss, I'll officially endorse Erik von Asmuth's code as the best code for the DLookup.  It's also important to understand your data, so I'm glad you learned something on that end, since this issue might cause problems down the road if you use such field data in other functions.  BTW, I'll guess that perhaps your [PCName]s have null characters from a native API call(?).  Such functions usually handle null-terminated strings.  If you have access to code which populates your tables, you could perhaps validate and scrub the data before it gets saved in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting your parameter from a form value, just use a form-based parameter. That avoids these kind of string-concatenation based errors:

```
Me.UN = DLookup("[UN]", "tbl_ComputerNames", "[PCName] = Forms![frm_CurrentConnections]!PCName")
```

Comment: This will likely work, but if the data has unexpected characters, like null termination as Rene pointed out, that may simply come back to haunt the OP, or cause other mysterious bugs later.  Is the goal to always just post the quickest answer that gets past an error, or to help identify and resolve the underlying problem?

Comment: @CPerkins The _programming problem_, imo, is that OP is using string concatenation for data that isn't properly validated. Answering that will likely benefit future readers the most, since it's a common mistake. Checking your data for undesired characters is a different subject altogether, but likely desirable, even if your program runs smoothly. However, feel free to write up your own answer if you doubt the quality of mine.

Comment: It goes without saying that I can post another question... I get that a lot, but I'm not afraid of a real conversation over votes.  **Your response emphasizes my point... that the "data isn't properly validated" and that "checking data... is a different subject altogether".**   The actual problem for this user is likely about data validation, not Dlookup, not string concatenation... despite the OP thinking and directing the question toward that subject.

Comment: Incorrect or invalid user input or stored data should not cause any code to generate a run-time error. Properly written code should not generate uncaught runtime errors, period. After correcting invalid data, the code should still be adjusted to handle any input without throwing uncaught errors. The fact that, if the data was validated, this error would not have occurred, doesn't mean that the string concatenation code wasn't flawed. Imo the _you should validate_ response is the quick way to get past it and my answer is fully valid here.

Comment: thanks you all for the speedy replies. I have added the exact error message from the debug window as requested - and I also thought that the position of the single quotes was odd- I did try removing the concatenation (Honestly did not know this was an option - Heller easier!) and this has worked but I am hesitant to call this solved from what CPerkins has advised regarding what Rene mentioned - the 'null termination' - I don't know what that is but I will google it now, to be sure...

Comment: Regarding the null terminator, this is a special character that indicates the end of a string in C/C++. You can test if a string contains a null terminator by testing in vba: `SomeString Like "*" & VbNullChar & "*"`, or in SQL, `SomeColumn LIKE '*' & Chr(0) & '*'`. Most functions that are internally implemented as C or C++ functions will ignore that character and all characters that follow it (for example, `MsgBox "123" & vbNullChar & "456"` will only show a message box containing 123). However, the database engine and most VBA functions can handle it fine, DLookUp just can't.

Comment: The `Replace` function can easily be used to strip null terminators: `Update MyTable Set MyColumn = Replace(MyColumn, Chr(0), '')` to strip them from strings. They usually occur in strings by handling WinAPI functions incorrectly.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  Very good points, and I appreciate the discussion.  I'm glad that your answer works well, and also glad that the discussion prompted deeper understanding of the OP.  Too often I've seen hastily accepted answers end discussion that was leading to such deeper understanding.

Comment: thank you all - I will bear in mind the Null Terminator in case future issues arise from this code... however to answer the Query about where I am getting the PCName from, - I found a function that reads the LACCDB files to ascertain the user currently logged in (this then uses another table with the users actual names to Dlookup the data) - I'm fairly confident that the way its being read is the cause of the Null Terminator - it uses ADODB and uses some "adSchemaProviderSpecific" string - it is using a "= Trim(rs.Fields(0))" action - was assuming this trimmed the odd 'non-text characters.